# OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. , errno = 123

Tags: flutter, dart

It is a very weird issue but while running my flutter app android studio says :

"FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin' & C:\src\flutter/bin/internal/exit_with_errorlevel.bat' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. , errno = 123)"

Now I believe the reason I am getting this error is the mixture if forward and backslash in the path above. But I am unable to find a way of how can I edit this path.

I checked in environment variables everything looks alright there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\src\flutter/bin/internal/exit_with_errorlevel.bat'

Did you notice that you're mixing up back-slashes and forward-slashes in that path?

On Windows you need to use back-slashes. (`\`)

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant. But just a day before. The program was working fine without any error. If you have any idea how I can edit the path here?

Comment: Sorry, man, no idea. I don't use Windows for development. Wish I could help.

Comment: Sad to know. Thanx anyways